# POST WNS notification via Perl?

Tags: perl, windows-8, push-notification

Is there a simple way to send WNS notificatons via Perl from an Apache server?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465407.aspx

I've tried oAuth lib and several other methods for posting this data to WNS, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol seems simple enough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx

It looks like the secrets are generated by Microsoft, so you'll still need to register for the Windows Store.